# How can I alter a post?

Tags: templates

I am using the lifter-lms plugin. In that plugin there are posts called *lessons*.

I basically want my lessons to be on a blank webpage; I want to disable almost everything off the lesson page, such as the sidebar, navigation menu, ect... I assume that I need to make some sort of template in order to do that.

What are the basic steps to create a custom lesson template? Or, is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: If the post type is called *lessons* you can leverage the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and create `single-lessons.php` within your theme/child theme and customize it to your liking. Third party plugins/themes are off-topic here on WPSE though, so if the lifter-lms plugin is doing something clever or strange you could run into issues, and if that's the case, reach out to the developers of that plugin directly.

Comment: That sounds good. How can I find the post type?

Comment: Try searching the plugin's files for `register_post_type`.